# Creating unique random numbers

Tags: java, random

I have created the following method so as to create unique random numbers . (This unique values belong to the nodes of a tree):

```
  static Random rand = new Random();
public static ArrayList<Node> go(int n) {
    ArrayList<Node> list = new ArrayList<Node>();
    ArrayList<Integer> numList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    for(int i = 1; i<=5; i++)
    {
        int number = rand.nextInt(10)+1;
        if(list.size()>0 && !check(list,number))
        {
            i--;
            continue;
        }
        numList.add(number);
        Node node = new Node();
        node.data = number;
        list.add(node);
    }
     int w  = 0;
    for (Node d : list) {
        System.out.println(w+": "+d.data);
        w++;
    }
    return list;

}
  private static boolean check(ArrayList<Node> list, int num) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    boolean b = false;
    /*if(list.size()==0)
        return true;
    */
    for (Node node : list) {
        if(node.data == num)
            b = false;
        else
            b = true;
    }
    return b;
}
```

But it doesn’t create unique numbers and there are still duplicates in my list. Like :

```
0: 10
1: 1 
2: 10 
3: 5 
4: 6
```

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using [Java SecureRandom](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html)?

Comment: SecureRandom provides unpredictable sequences. There are many non security uses of Random where predictably is not an issue, and a few where reproduction of the same sequences is desired.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you don't stop the for loop inside the check function if it finds a duplicated number. The loop continues and b can change back to true.

What you should do is for example:

```
  private static boolean check(ArrayList<Node> list, int num) {
    for (Node node : list) {
        if(node.data == num)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: actually it should be the opposite: returning `false` on duplicate and `true` at the end

Answer (score 3):

Jón Trausti Arason has your answer, but...

Since you have a finite number of allowed values (integers), and since you don't want the same one picked more than once, perhaps it would be easier to just [shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) an array of the allowed values.  Then you could just pick off the next value from the array and not worry about checking every time whether it's a repeat.

In your example selecting five values between one and ten, you could start with an array `{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}` and run it through a shuffle to rearrange it to something else like `{3,4,7,1,10,9,5,8,2,6}`.  Take the first five values out of that resulting array with no worries about repeats.

Answer (score 1):

In your check method, this looks a bit dodgy:

```
if (node.data == num) 
  b = false;
else
  b = true
```

Surely once you've found a match (e.g. b = false) you want to return?  Otherwise the next time around the loop b might be set to true.  To simplify a bit, if you want to check whether an item is in a collection you can do list.contains(element)

Answer (score 1):

You "forget" to use the `numList` that you've prepared.

This code should work fine:

```
static Random rand = new Random();

public static ArrayList<Node> go(int n) {
    ArrayList<Node> list = new ArrayList<Node>();
    ArrayList<Integer> numList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        int number = rand.nextInt(10) + 1;
        if (numList.contains(number)) {
            i--;
            continue;
        }
        numList.add(number);
        Node node = new Node();
        node.data = number;
        list.add(node);
    }
    int w = 0;
    for (Node d : list) {
        System.out.println(w + ": " + d.data);
        w++;
    }
    return list;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

To illustrate on @eaj's point.

```
public static List<Node> go(int n) {
    List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) numbers.add(i);
    Collections.shuffle(numbers);
    List<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<Node>();
    for (Integer data : numbers.subList(0, 5))
        nodes.add(new Node(data)); // use a constructor for Node.
    for (int w = 0; w < nodes.size(); w++)
        System.out.println(w + ": " + nodes.get(w).data);
    return nodes;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! :) I had forgotten that the shuffle was in the Collections API.

Answer (score 0):

Your `check` function is wrong. Currently, it simply returns whether the *last* element matches `num`. You want to declare `true` (e.g. with `return true;`) once you find a match.

In fact, you can do everything without `b`. And I'm sure you can use `list`'s `contain` method instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should change your `check` method to something like:

```
  private static boolean check(ArrayList<Node> list, int num)
  {
    for (Node node : list)
        if (node.data == num)
            return false;

    return true;
  }
```

In this way you go over the list and return `false` as soon as you find an equal element. If you are able to finish the loop without returning then no duplicates are found and you can return `true`.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;


public class comboGenerator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


    ArrayList<Integer> $combo = new ArrayList<Integer>();       // init. array list combo for randomization


        while ($combo.size() < 6) {  
            int rand = (int) (Math.random()*49+1);          // make new random number 1-49
            if (!$combo.contains(rand)){                    // check if we have that number in array list,{
            $combo.add(rand);                               // if there is no such number then add it to array list
            Collections.sort($combo);                       // sort the array list small >> large
            }
        }

    System.out.println("Random combination " + $combo);

}   
}
```

And you CAN'T get same numbers!