# How to make a int not be used twice when it randomly generates them?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I've coded a simple quiz game for Android, and currently Im having troubles with making questions not appear after they've been shown, i.o. I dont want it to ask me the same question twice..

This is the method Im using

```
 private void QBegin() {
   /*
    * Gets a random question
    */
    question = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
    String[] types = { "Question one",
            "Question two", 
            "Question three", 
            "Question four",
            "Question five"};
    Random random = new Random();
    int qType = random.nextInt(types.length);
    question.setText(types[qType]);
    getAnswers(qType); //gets four answers
}
```

Im not sure if this will work but, what if I add something like

Edit : Doesn't work..

```
    int i = 0;
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list.add(qType);
    i++;
    if(list.contains(qType) && i != types.length + 1){
        return;
    } else {
        answerCounter.setText("Hit the bricks pal, you're done..");
    }
```

Edit 2: Got told to add something like this, but I have NO IDEA what I should be doing with this now..

```
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list.add(types.length);
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    if(!list.contains(qType)){
        // help please, as I have no idea on what I should be doing!
    }
```

Comment: Aaaand it didn't work...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating unique random numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410225/creating-unique-random-numbers)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest approach would be to generate an `ArrayList` of all the possible numbers you want to use, the shuffle them with [`Collection.shuffle`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29). Then just iterate over the list.

EDIT: Your question is *really* unclear now, given that you've said you *don't* want the questions in a random order... whereas your sample code appears to be trying to present the questions in a random order. Anyway... here's what I was suggesting:

```
List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
     indexes.add(i);
}
Collections.shuffle(indexes);

for (Integer index : indexes) {
    question.setText(types[index]);
    getAnswers(index);
    // Now do something else? It's unclear...
}
```

Comment: Ah, you didn't get it, did you? I mean, Im trying to make it so that it won't ask me the same question again, dont see the reason in using a shuffle method, sorry.

Comment: @John: Yes, I *did* get it - you effectively put all the questions (or indexes) into a list, then shuffle the list. Then you can just iterate over the list, and you'll get all the questions, in a random order, with no repeats. If that's not what you're after, please clarify.

Comment: I dont wan't them to appear in a random order,

Comment: I want them to not appear at all (after I've been asked) , e.g. I get asked question one, and after awhile I can get asked the same question.. and I dont want that.  PS. Excuse me for my awful English.

Comment: Ouch, you just offended the god of StackOverflow. Pray he does not divide you with zero ;) Btw, Jon's answer is correct - you only shuffle once then iterate through list. This way question will not be repeated. When you get to the end of the list you know you are out of questions.

Comment: Ohh, ok gotcha, but can I please have an example of what I should be doing? I know you guys dont have to, and probably even dont want to, but still.. (please)

Comment: Added this      ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(types.length);
     Collections.shuffle(list);, but now I have no idea what to do next..

Comment: You need to put your questions inside the list, and only then, shuffle the list. Shuffling an empty list makes no sense. Once all the questions are in the list, in a random order, iterate over the list.

Comment: It's not empty, since 'new ArrayList<Integer>(types.length);' , and can I use types.length (int) instead of a question (String)?

Comment: `new ArrayList<Integer>(types.length);` just creates a new list of size `types.length`. It's still empty. Where do you think it's getting the information from?

Comment: Try using a `for` loop to insert each `int` from `0` (inclusive) to `types.length` (exclusive).

Comment: Can someone just edit the code for me? I know I shouldn't ask for this, but I seriously have no idea on what I should be doing.. and it will be just better/easier to show me what I should be doing, rather than telling me 'do that' , 'you're doing that wrong, so do this'

Comment: @John: SO is for code help, not code answers.  There are other sites for providing code answers.  Note that such sites cost money.

Comment: No, that won't be easier, and will hurt you in the long run. It's a VERY basic concept that you need to be able to grasp. You create a list of size `n`. You then insert `n` objects of the list's data type (integer, in your example). You then shuffle this list. You now have a list in random (semi-random) order.

Comment: @Brian, but my question isn't that hard, I'm sure most of you know what I am doing wrong, but can't seem to help me by editing the code it self. I know this website isn't ment to provide me with such things, but I know that Im asking for a simple thing, and was hoping someone would help me out, as I'm stuck, and cannot move further.

Comment: @ kcoppock I dont need it to be random.  ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list.add(types.length);
    Collections.shuffle(list), and it wont hurt me, but if you think so, don't help the way you don't want to, thanks anyway.

Comment: @John: No, but you should want it to be. If your quiz ran in the same order every time, it would be a pretty boring application. You randomize the list, then iterate over the list. If the list contains no duplicates, then by definition you will not repeat any questions. `"but my question isn't that hard."` You're right, it isn't. But if you're stuck on this, how are you supposed to finish the more difficult portions of the application?

Comment: @kcoppock: I understand, but something I still don't get it, even with all these people telling me what to do.. after adding this     ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    list.add(types.length);
    Collections.shuffle(list); what exactly I should be doing now?

Comment: ALL STOP on the comments please; please don't hold extended conversations in comments.

Comment: What I ment was , it's already in a random order, so I dont need to know how to make it random.

Comment: and What Im trying to do is, I am trying to make it so that I won't get asked the same question again.

Comment: I guess I could use indexes.remove(index), to remove it from the list, but it does  for (int i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
          indexes.add(i) , i.o. re adds it?

Comment: @John: If it's already in a random order, you don't need to use any other source of randomness, do you? Just keep a counter starting at 0 and increment it each time you ask a question. Your question is still unclear in terms of where you want this randomness to come in, basically.

Comment: Basicly this... int i = 0;      if (i >= types.length) {
      answerCounter.setText("Hit the bricks pal, you're done");
      finished = true;
      return;
     }  i++;     question.setText(types[i]);
    getAnswers(i);  ... but in a random order

Comment: @John: But I thought you said they were *already* in a random order? You're being inconsistent. Please read through your question and all your comments to see where the confusion is coming from, and then edit your question to clarify. Either you need to be given code to introduce randomness (in which case use `Collections.shuffle`) or you don't (in which case just keep a counter).

Comment: @JonSkeet I didn't ment to say that I dont need randomness, and I understood where I was wrong, I had to make it so that it creates the list then uses shuffle method to make it random only once, but instead I had it a method that kept re-adding & shuffling everything. I.o. Everything's fine now, thanks to you.

Answer (score 1):

Simple algorithm below:

You need generate value from 0 to N without repeatings.

1. Define an array with those elements [0..N] (array[n])
2. Generate random number in interval [0..N] (rand)
3. Choose in array element, where generated value is index (array[rand])
4. Swap these element with the last in array (swap array[rand] <-> array[N])
5. Next time you generate index in [0..N-1] so in that case previously generated element won't be selected.

Comment: That sounds remarkably like what Collections.shuffle does for you. Why do the work yourself when a single method call can do all the heavy lifting? Granted it's not really *that* heavy, but even so... (Note that you don't want to swap with the *last* element every time, otherwise you'll be swapping the previously chosen element back into play on the next iteration.)

Comment: (Just reading this again, maybe your last step was meant to effectively be "decrement N" in which case it would work, of course - but I'd still rather use Shuffle.)

Comment: Sure, you decrement N, and swap with this element

Comment: >> Why do the work yourself when a single method call can do all the heavy lifting? Although, shuffle is a nice solution for current problem, imagine that you have 1 million questions and you need choose 3 random. In that case shuffle all list will be not very effectively.

Comment: In that case this solution won't be particularly efficient either - it would be more efficient to just pick a number at random and check whether or not you've already used it. But if you've already got an O(n) operation (populating the array/list) then using another O(n) operation (shuffling everything) at least isn't changing the *complexity*.

Comment: >> pick a number at random and check whether or not you've already used it.          It can be a real solution but theoretically you can't guarantee that your algorithm will be finite. You have (very very low) probability pull always the same number.

Comment: In reality, which do you think you'd *actually* use? Something that is theoretically infinite but practically quick, or something which is guaranteed but always slow?

Comment: I agree with you. But in our case we not compare slow and quick, both of them has equal complexity.

Comment: So why did you ask me to imagine the situation where you have a million questions? In what situation is your solution a more appropriate one to use than Collections.shuffle?

Comment: In situation where time is critical and we don't have attempt to fail. As i said in your case you can generate the same number twice (without shuffle) and with shuffle you waste time on shuffling procedure

Comment: I think I'll wait until I'm in that very rare scenario before I write extra code :)