# Creating unique random numbers in Java

Tags: java

I was making a Random number (sort of a guessing game) and have come up with the ff. code to generate 10 one or two-digit numbers(1 or 10 up to 40):

```
public void generate()
{
    for(int i=0; i<=1; i++)
    {
        for(int l=0; l<10; l++)
        {
            Random rdm=new Random();
            arr[l] = rdm.nextInt(range)+1;

        }
    }
}
```

However, this code only answers the need to generate 10 random one or two-digit numbers. I need to make this program generate unique random numbers. How can I do that?

sorry for the late update... what I want to do with this program is that if the array contains a duplicate, that duplicate would be replaced with a unique one...

==============SOLVED================

NEW PROBLEM:

```
HashSet set=new HashSet();
Random random=new Random();

while(set.Size()<10)
{
    set.add(random.nextInt(range)+1);
}

lbtest.setText(set.toString());
bgen.setEnabled(false);
gametext.setText("");
```

As requested by ggrigery:

here's the updated code in reference to ggrigery's suggestion.

Comment: you can use a structure, `ArrayList` for example, to store previously generated numbers and then check to see if the new number is in that list.

Comment: See also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410225/creating-unique-random-numbers), which has an almost-working implementation.

Comment: +1 to get this back to 0, not sure why it was voted down as it seems like a valid question to me. You want to use a Set, see my answer below :)

Comment: @Paul I think it's being used to mean [following](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ff.#Abbreviation), which would be unusual but I suppose valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
    Random random = new Random();
    int i = 0;

    while(set.size() < 10){
        set.add(random.nextInt(40) + 1);
        i++;
    }

    System.out.println(set);
    System.out.println(i);
```

Comment: QUESTION: how do i display the elements from the set(HashSet)? does it replace the duplicates once found within the set?

Comment: Sets cannot contain duplicates by nature. Set.add() returns a boolean; true if the element does not exist and it was added to the set, false if the addition "failed". If you add a counter to that code, you will see that the loop generally executes more than 10 times.

Comment: To answer your display question, try `System.out.println(set)`. The default `toString()` method will print out the elements like [element1, element2, ....]. I have updated the code with a counter, try running it and see what happens.

Comment: @ggrigery_you're right! thanks for that! but i got an error in my attempt to display the set in a label via lbtest.setText(""+set);

error: cannot find symbol(pointed at the period >set.add<

Comment: try `setText(set.toString);`. In my code above, the toString() is implicitly called. If you want to pass a `String`, you will need to explicitly call the `toString()` method.

Comment: @griggery_error still points to the period >>set.add<<.
im at a loss as to what have caused this error since i checked the spelling quite a few times... and i didn't find any misdeclaration or mispelling...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't completely read the error. The error does not appear to be related to `setText()`. Can you update the code you are using now in your original question and we can look if you have any syntax issues?

Comment: @ggrigery_how do i compare this to an answer and if the element is equal to the answer then score +10. however, if that same answer is entered a second time, the user's lives should decrement.

Comment: @cryzone I'm not sure I understand your question. Can you be more specific? Compare what and what?

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to use shuffle.

```
List<Integer> all = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=1;i<=range;i++) all.add(i);
Collections.shuffle(all);
List<Integer> selected = all.subList(0, 10);
```

If you are selecting every element, it can take a long time to find the last random value if you are discarding duplicates.  This approach takes the same amount of time whether you select one or all elements.

Answer (score 0):

Do a search inside the array to know if the value is there:

```
private boolean isInsideArray(int randomNumber, int[] arr){
    for(int x = 0; x < arr.length; x++){
        if(arr[x] == randomNumber) return true;

    }
    return false;
}
```

Just call this function when you want to know if a number is inside the array.

NOTE: this code is untested, it is just an example to help you out. Also not the most elegant solution, there are many methods in Java that can help you accomplish this without cycling the entire array.

Comment: I think you meant to put the `return false` after the loop. Also, if you use an `ArrayList`, you get `ArrayList.contains`, and an `ArrayList` is much better for this situation.

Comment: the guy is just doing homework to learn the loops. Agreed that an arraylist is better, this solution is better for what he is learning today. Don't worry, he will learn the ArrayLists very soon :)

Answer (score 0):

Set guarantees unique elements. Then you may take result and convert it in whatever collection or array you want.

```
public List<Integer> generate() {
   Random random = new Random();
   Set<Integer> set = new LinkedHashSet<Integer>();
   for(int i = 0; i < numberCount; i++) {
      set.add(random.nextInt(range));
   }
   return new ArrayList<Integer>(set);
}
```

Comment: I don't really know Java's structures, but I think that won't keep generating numbers until there are `numberCount`; it'll just eliminate the duplicates.

Comment: Q: does this code generate 10 one or two-digit random numbers?

Comment: I didn't see this answer before posting my own. Mine is the same concept, but mine will guarantee that the set is 10 numbers in the range of 1-40 (inclusive).

Answer (score 0):

```
public void generate() {
    Random rdm = new Random();
    int i = 0;
    while (i < 10) {
        int j = rdm.nextInt(range) + 1;
        if (!arrayContains(j)) {
            arr[i] = j;
            i++;
        }
    }   
}

public boolean arrayContains(int i) {
    for (int k = 0; k < arr.length; k++) {
        if (arr[k] == i)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

This should do the job. Could be more elegant though.

Comment: @arkk_what does this mean if(!arrayContains(j))?

Comment: @cryzone, if(!arrayContains(j)) can be read in English as "if arrayContains(j) is not true".